# Replace PHP values in $_POST (for mailing)

Tags: php, forms

This is driving me crazy and I couldn't find information that could help me figure this out.

I have a simple check-in form as follows:

```
<label for="adults" class="field-label"> Adults</label>
  <label class="field select prepend-icon">
   <select  id="adults" name="adults" onChange="updatesum()">
     <option value="0">...</option>
     <option value="300">1</option>
     <option value="600">2</option>
     <option value="900">3</option>
   </select>
</label>
```

Those option values are prices used to calculate the price per person and the text is actually the amount of adults checkin-in.
What I can't figure out is that when I submit the form the PHP posts the value of the field instead of the amount of adults checking in which are between 1 and 3 max.

```
$adults = strip_tags(trim($_POST["adults"]));
```

Can i replace that values before sending the email to something like this:

```
If the value = 300 then replace with 1
If the value = 600 then replace with 2
If the value = 900 then replace with 3
```

and then send the email with the number of adults and not the price.

Can anybody give me a hand?? thanks!!

You can check it live here [westermansfrigga.se](http://westermansfrigga.se) and  press the button "boka nu", that's the form I'm making.
It's still in testing phase you can make test bokings and you should get the corresponding emails. For a clear understanding of what I mean with replacing the values. In the confirmation email adults = 300 instead of 1.

Comment: Why don't you just change the value to be 1, 2, 3 instead of 300, 600, 900 ?!?

Comment: Can you show us the bit in your email code that puts the values in

Comment: because I have a script that sums the value and calculates the price:

Comment: can you not simply do value / 300 ?

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of your form is the expected one. The **value** of the field is sent, not its text. So

```
<option value="ThisWillBeSent">This will NOT be sent</option>
```

I imagine that you use "value" for some operation on `onChange` (so if I were you, **I would add that script to the question**). The best solution would be to have a different attribute holding the number:

```
<option data-value="300" value="1">One Adult</option>
```

This way, the number of adults gets sent, and the client still has the amount to work upon. In the javascript you read the new attribute, e.g. in jQuery,

```
sum += $el.attr("data-value")
```

instead of

```
sum += $el.attr("value")
```

If you're using plain Javascript, then you would have something like

```
var combo      = document.getElementById("adults");
var adultValue = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-value");
```

To replace values server side, in PHP, you can use `switch`:

```
switch ($valueIn) {
   case 300:  $valueOut = 1; break;
   case 600:  $valueOut = 2; break;
   case 900:  $valueOut = 3; break;
   default:
       // Throw some error, to be warned should you ever change
       // the client side array and get an unknown value such as 1200.
 }
```

(or, in *this* case, also `$valueOut = $valueIn / 300`).

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to add an error reporting to the default clause -- give it six months, and you'll be glad you did. I speak from unpleasant experience :-)